# Deploying flask with sqlite to heroku

Tags: sqlite, flask, heroku

When I push my app to Heroku it does use the `data_base.db` and if i try to add a user to the data base I get the error that no data base is found

```
2021-08-15T13:02:39.226938+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2021-08-15T13:02:39.226938+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users
```

Does heroku forbid the use of sqlite  or am I doing something wrong

This is `config.py`

```
import random 
import string 


class Config:

    SECRET_KEY = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(60))

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///data_base.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    



class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True 

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False 

config = {
    'dev' : DevelopmentConfig,
    'prod': ProductionConfig,
    }
```

Comment: I don't think they _forbid_ it exactly, but even if you put migrations in place to bootstrap the database structure all of your data will be lost every time the dyno reboots (daily, at minimum): https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///data_base.db'
```

with

```
uri = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = uri or 'sqlite:///data_base.db'
```

simply tells the app to use `postgresql` when deployed to heroku

and don't forget to add `psycopg2` to the `requirements.txt` file